# Connection between Lagrangian and (pre)symplectic structure

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, mathematical-physics, symmetry

How is the precise relationship between a Lagrangian and the (pre)symplectic structure?

Given a (pre)symplectic structure can I construct a (equivalence class of) Lagrangian(s)?

References are very welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Given a Lagrangian $L$, it is in principle possible to perform a (possible singular) Legendre transformation using e.g. the [Faddeev-Jackiw method](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9306075) to arrive at a Hamiltonian Lagrangian of the form
   $$L_H(z,\dot{z},t)~=~\vartheta_I(z,t)~\dot{z}^I - H(z,t)\tag{6}$$
   with a Hamiltonian $H$ and a pre-symplectic potential $$\vartheta~=~\vartheta_I(z,t)~\mathrm{d}z^I, \qquad \omega~:=~\mathrm{d}\vartheta.  $$
2. Conversely, given a Hamiltonian $H$ and a pre-symplectic potential $\vartheta$, the Hamiltonian Lagrangian (6) provides a Lagrangian formulation.